# How to validate Django model in form without submit?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I need to validate Model somewhere deep in code. F.e. for grant access to a few pages.

How can I validate ModelForm against model instance without generating fake POST/GET data?

Comment: What do you mean *"fake POST/GET data"*?

Comment: Post your code. What have you tried? More information I think would help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass dictionary for you form and validate form after it.

```
form = YourForm (your_dict)
form.validate ()
```

You can also generate dict automatically from django model by this:

```
from django.forms import model_to_dict

your_dict = model_to_dict(your_object
    fields = ["fields to include"]
    exclude = ["fields to exclude"]
)
```

Comment: Thanks, model_to_dict is what I needed :)